# Access query - filter related issues

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a problem with ms-access query. I would like to have a review panel where we could switch quickly project using multiple filters as needed.
Because of that I created access query and put a parameter under criteria filed in the column to be filtered. Parameter is taken from a field in Review_Form. It works if I put a particular number but I do not know what to input to receive all records without filtering them. I tried a few different approaches but without success. I have used e.g. examples shown in the link below:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-criteria-to-text-values-202548b6-b065-4387-800b-2456a7099bca
The whole idea is shown in the attached picture:
[image]

Please let me know if you have any suggestions, ideas how to solve it.
Thank you,
Piotr

Solution provided by Andre works but only if there is a 1 filter. In my case I would like to use more filters. Trying to apply any strings values as (Is Not Null) or (Like) to obtain all records for a particular filters it ends with an error as before.
In other words: If I type directly inside access query sting e.g. (Is Not Null) it will work, but if I am trying to use fields inside the ViewProject form to have instead numerical values string, it results in error.
Do you have any suggestion how to overcome that?

Comment: The problem you are having is an Operator problem. In the case where you change status to a star "*" you have to use the "Like" operator instead of the "=" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution is to make the condition always TRUE when the status filter = 3

Change your WHERE condition in SQL view like so:

```
WHERE ((Status.id_status = Forms!ViewProject!pstatus1) OR (Forms!ViewProject!pstatus1 = 3))
```

Then you don't need the translation in VBA. You could also directly reference `T_project_s1` in the query, and not need the sub at all.

Comment: This answers my question. I just need to take a while to understand it. I mean why this condition is always true?

Comment: However it works as I described when there is only one filter. Is there a way it would work for multiple filters?

Comment: For multiple filters, append additional conditions with AND. See http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html --> "Using a query instead". Alternatively, build the filter with VBA (same link).

Comment: Thank you Andre. There is exact description of issue I am now facing with good answer.